# React OptionList not showing any options

Tags: jquery, reactjs, frontend, web3js

im trying to fill two option lists from this functions, the option list with id="frames" is working as expected, but the one with id="nonFramesComponent" is not working at all:

```
const getSmbFrameNfts = async () => {
    const connection = await new Connection('mainnet-beta');
    const ownerPublicKey = walletAddress;
    const nftsmetadata = await Metadata.findDataByOwner(connection, ownerPublicKey);

    const frames = [];

    for (var i in nftsmetadata) {
      if (nftsmetadata[i].data.symbol == 'FRAME') {
        fetch(nftsmetadata[i].data.uri)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((findresponse) => {
            frames.push(findresponse);
          })
      }
    }
    return frames;
  }




const getNonFrameNfts = async () => {
    const connection = await new Connection('mainnet-beta');
    const ownerPublicKey = walletAddress;
    const nftsmetadata = await Metadata.findDataByOwner(connection, ownerPublicKey);

    const frames = [];

    for (var i in nftsmetadata) {
      if (nftsmetadata[i].data.symbol != 'FRAME') {
        fetch(nftsmetadata[i].data.uri)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((findresponse) => {
            frames.push(findresponse);
          })
      }
    }
    return frames;
  }
```

This is the function that populate my optionLists

```
const populateListsWithNfts = async () => {
        const frames = await getFrames();
        const nonFramesArr = await getNonFrames();
        console.log(nonFramesArr[0]);
        var frameStr = '';
        var nonFrameStr = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
            frameStr += '<option value="' + frames[i].name + '"/>'
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < nonFramesArr.length; ++j) {
            nonFrameStr += '<option value="' + nonFramesArr[j].name + '"/>'
        }


        document.getElementById("nonFramesComponent").innerHTML = await nonFrameStr;
        document.getElementById("frames").innerHTML = frameStr;
    }
```

It is printing undefined on nonFramesArr[0] and if i print the whole array it shows this:
[image]

"This value was evaluated upon first expanding, it may have changed since then"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using react states hooks, solution below:

- Added these states

  const [nonFrameNfts, setNonFrameNfts] = useState(null);
  const [frameNfts, setFrameNfts] = useState(null);
- Refactored useEffect as follow:

  useEffect(() => {
  const onLoad = async () => {
  await setFrameNfts(await getFrames());
  await setNonFrameNfts(await getNonFrames());
  await populateListsWithNfts();
  }
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  onLoad();
  } else {
  window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("load", onLoad);
  }
  }, [])
- Changed populateListsWithNfts method:

  const populateListsWithNfts = async () => {
  const frames = frameNfts;
  const nonFramesArr = nonFrameNfts;